# What is the proper preposition following 'appendix'?

Tags: prepositions

In the following sentence, 'The graph can be found in the appendix [preposition] this report', what is the correct preposition to use? In particular, is 'to' more appropriate than 'of'?

Comment: Methinks their meanings differ. *Appendix to* designates the document to which the appendix has been, well, appended. *Appendix of* designates the contents of the appendix itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't object to *appendix for*, *appendix of*, *appendix behind*, *appendix following*, and so on, but by the NGram, ***appendix to*** is favored by a wide margin:

[image: Google Books NGram showing 'appendix to' being much more prevalent than 'appendix for' or 'appendix of']

There may be some false hits here as *appendix* can also refer to an internal organ, among other things, but since those uses would be overwhelmingly *appendix of* (e.g. *The appendix of a ruminant, unlike the appendix of an ape, is a true appendix, or* cecum), the point stands.

Comment: Shoot, I *just* found the Ngram site! I was about to post the same but you beat me to it. I would also like to point out that the popularity of "appendix to" is rapidly declining, while "appendix of" is steadily increasing.

Comment: For some reason, which I cannot figure out, most of the extra instances of "appendix to this" are part of *"appendix to this chapter"*, and if you remove them then the frequencies of *"to"* and *"of"* are much closer. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=appendix+of+this%2C(appendix+to+this)+-+(appendix+to+this+chapter)&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cappendix%20of%20this%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28appendix%20to%20this%29%20-%20%28appendix%20to%20this%20chapter%29%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Nice find @PeterShor! To be fair, of course, [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(appendix+of+this)+-+(appendix+of+this+chapter)%2C(appendix+to+this)+-+(appendix+to+this+chapter)&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28appendix%20of%20this%29%20-%20%28appendix%20of%20this%20chapter%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28appendix%20to%20this%29%20-%20%28appendix%20to%20this%20chapter%29%3B%2Cc0) should probably be the query.

Comment: Hello! How about this [direct query](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=appendix+*+this+report&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cappendix%20%2A%20this%20report%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bappendix%20to%20this%20report%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bappendix%20of%20this%20report%3B%2Cc0) on the OP expression? *To* with dominance by a factor of 3 and much less obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

Both "to" and "of" are *appropriate*, although I prefer **"of"**. "To" has more of a detached sense, which may be more appropriate if it was in a separate book, PDF, etc. "Of" makes the appendix inherently feel more a part of the whole report.

Answer (score 0):

An appendix, or more appendices, is, or are, appended *to* the text. For this reason, *appendix to* surely sounds more natural.

Answer (score -2):

An appendix is something that has been appended to a document.  Therefore, you would describe it as the appendix *to* the document.

The appendix does not belong to the document.  Therefore describing it as the appendix *of* the document is incorrect.

An appendix is not part of the document.  If it were, it would be a chapter or a section.

Comment: I would most definitely call the appendix to a book part of the book. It's usually not in a separate volume.